# Remove Clip board from Shell

Tags: linux, command-line, clipboard

I have been trying to remove the feature clip board copy to Shell.
We have requirement to disable the feature where we can copy paste from windows & then paste to the console via Putty to avoid any erroneous input.
Is this possible. I have going through all info but not much clear how exactly this can be done
Please help

Abhinav

Comment: If the issue is accidental right-click causing unintended paste, then how about going to Settings / Window  / Selection and choosing "Windows" as Action of mouse.

Comment: Well , that fine.... But i am trying to completely disable this so no body can ever do so willingly too... can you please guide Paul !!

Comment: Thanks Paul !!! Got your points....never thought it will be so easy thanks a lot !!!